# redirect to the same url from which request is sent

Tags: python, django, django-views

## views.py

```
def login_user(request):
    if request.POST:
        sform = LoginForm(request.POST)
        rform = UserForm()
        if sform.is_valid():
            username = request.POST.get('username')
            password = request.POST.get('password')
            user = authenticate(username = username,password = password)
            if user is not None:
                if user.is_active:
                    login(request,user)
                    return redirect(request.path)
                else:
                    state = "Your account is not active."
                    #or first set the user to is active and then log in 
                    return redirect('acitvate_account',user = user)
                return render_to_response('home.html',{'state':state,'user':user},context_instance = RequestContext(request))
            else:
                state = "Incorrect Username or Password"
                #sform = LoginForm()
                form = LoginForm()
                return render_to_response('register.html',{'state':state,'sform':sform,'rform':rform,'form':form},context_instance = RequestContext(request))
        else:
            state = "Invalid form"
            dLoginForm = LoginForm()
            rform = PartialSignupForm()
            return render_to_response('register.html',{'sform':sform,'rform':rform,'form':form},context_instance = RequestContext(request))
    else:
        dLoginForm = LoginForm()
        rform = PartialSignupForm()
        return render_to_response('category.html',{'dLoginForm':dLoginForm,'rform':rform},context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

## urls.py

```
urlpatterns += patterns('beenthere.views',
    #beenthere urls
    (r'^$','index'),
    (r'^home2/$','category'),
    (r'^accounts/login/$','login_user'),
    (r'^accounts/register/$','register_user'),
    (r'^home/(?P<user>\w*)$','home'),
    (r'^logout/','logout_user'),

    )
```

## doubt

how am i suppose to redirect the same url from which request is sent , i tried using request.path but it redirects me to the /accounts/login/ url , which is not desired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is track what the referrer was when you displayed the login form, possibly storing that value in the users session, then redirect the user back to that url once they've successfully logged in.

Something along the lines of:

```
def login_user(request):
    if request.POST:
        sform = LoginForm(request.POST)
        rform = UserForm()
        if sform.is_valid():
            username = request.POST.get('username')
            password = request.POST.get('password')
            user = authenticate(username = username,password = password)
            if user is not None:
                if user.is_active:
                    login(request,user)
                    return redirect(request.path)
                else:
                    state = "Your account is not active."
                    #or first set the user to is active and then log in 
                    return redirect(req.session['after_login_url'],user = user)
                return render_to_response('home.html',{'state':state,'user':user},context_instance = RequestContext(request))
            else:
                state = "Incorrect Username or Password"
                #sform = LoginForm()
                form = LoginForm()
                return render_to_response('register.html',{'state':state,'sform':sform,'rform':rform,'form':form},context_instance = RequestContext(request))
        else:
            state = "Invalid form"
            dLoginForm = LoginForm()
            rform = PartialSignupForm()
            return render_to_response('register.html',{'sform':sform,'rform':rform,'form':form},context_instance = RequestContext(request))
    else:
        dLoginForm = LoginForm()
        rform = PartialSignupForm()
        req.session['after_login_url'] = req.META.get('HTTP_REFERER')
        return render_to_response('category.html',{'dLoginForm':dLoginForm,'rform':rform},context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

Of course you should also add checks to make sure that the HTTP_REFERER header exists, and make sure the `after_login_url` key exists (and possibly has a sane value, in case an external site links directly to your log in page, or similar), and have a safe fall back if any of these tests fail (like maybe a user's profile page, or your sites index page).

Comment: thanks joe  , but aint there any simplre solution , what if i directly use request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER') to redirect

Comment: When the form is submitted HTTP_REFERER will be the log in form itself.  HTTP_REFERER is the URL the user is coming from when they loaded the current page, so if you want to use that to redirect them after submitting the form, you have to grab it as they are initially viewing the form.

Comment: yea yea i got your point , but i was using login form and registration form on the same page and those were dialog forms , so it was kind of dynamic , so HTTP_REFERER was the same url i wanted it to redirect , so it was working in my case , but ur solution is more generalized , thanks